# Java process crashes on Linux (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: java, ubuntu, crash

I have a Java process ran from shell script on Ubuntu 14.04, that crashes abnormally without any visible reason and no logs. The Java program uses Twitter's Userstream API. I've been looking for traces in /var/log but did not find anything that could explicitly point to a problem. Please advise how approach this issue and find any useful log that could indicate the problem.
Also, this is my Java version:

```
Java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question and add the output of `java -version`. Additionally, information about what the java program does might be helpful.

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: I also sent in *another* edit to fix the markdown

Answer (score 0):

The first step in troubleshooting HotSpot crashes is to locate a crash log, alternatively called fatal error log. By default, these are named `hs_err_pid%pid.log`, with `%pid` being the process ID of the crashed VM, and can usually be found in the cwd where the process started. The name and location of said log can also be influenced through the `-XX:ErrorFile`-VM parameter. Example:

`-XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/java/java_error%pid.log`.

You can find more information about the crash logs themselves [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/felog.html).

The contents of that log can give an indication on what happened, and where approximately. Be prepared tho, that situations in which a HotSpot crash occurs, are usually *not* caused by mere bugs in the hosted Java program. An extensive guide to interpreting these crash logs can be found here [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/crashes.html).

If no such log can be located after a crash, odds are the VM did not crash, but terminated normally. In that case, a remote debugging session might be in order. Remote debugging is detailed [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat) and also has some topics on SO already.

(There's the very remote chance that circumstances do not permit the log to be written, i.e. no available file handles during the crash.)

Comment: The hs_err_pid%pid.log file is absent, but VM did not terminate normally because application log stops in the middle. Can the OS stop the process for some reason and how can I check that this really happened?

Comment: I see you found the reason, congrats! Would have been an important info that it always crashes right when you log out ;)

Comment: Absolutely, if I knew. I wrote in question "...crashes abnormally without any visible reason...". I found the cause for crash later. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Sure, no problem, have a great time :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my process terminated when I disconnected SSH from the server. In order to run the process in background and prevent process termination when disconnected use 'nohup':

> ~$ nohup *process_name* &

I found the answer in this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89483/keeping-a-process-running-after-putty-or-terminal-has-been-closed/89487#89487).